# 'Linear' object has no attribute 'dim'

Tags: python, pytorch

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код и получаю ошибку:

````
import torch.nn.functional as F


class TF(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TF, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(28, 56, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(56, 112, 3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 10)
        self.soft=nn.LogSoftmax(dim=0)
       

    def forward(self, x):
        x=x.cuda()
        x = x.view(-1, 28,28)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1
        x = self.fc2
        x = self.fc3
        x = F.softmax(x)
        return x

tf=TF().to('cuda')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(tf.parameters())

```for epoch in range(10):  
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = tf(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-535-b76e0de90a8b> in <module>
>     10         optimizer.zero_grad()
>     11 
>---> 12         outputs = tf(inputs)
>     13         print(outputs)
>     14         loss = F.nll_loss(outputs, labels)

>~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, >*input, **kwargs)
>    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>    888         else:
>--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
>    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

><ipython-input-530-89adabe7361f> in forward(self, x)
>     24         x = self.fc2
>     25         x = self.fc3
>---> 26         x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
>    27         return x

>~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in log_softmax(input, >dim, _stacklevel, dtype)
>   1670         dim = _get_softmax_dim("log_softmax", input.dim(), >_stacklevel)
>   1671     if dtype is None:
>-> 1672         ret = input.log_softmax(dim)
>   1673     else:
>   1674         ret = input.log_softmax(dim, dtype=dtype)

>~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __getattr__(self, >name)
>    945             if name in modules:
>    946                 return modules[name]
>--> 947         raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute >'{}'".format(
>    948             type(self).__name__, name))
>    949 

>AttributeError: 'Linear' object has no attribute 'log_softmax'
````

Comment: Вставьте прямо в вопрос, пожалуйста, весь стейтрейс. Нельзя так одну единственную строчку запостить и надеяться, что по ней все понятно.

Comment: а это точно весь код ? гдеже обращение к атрибуту дим ?

Comment: for epoch in range(10):  
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]

        # обнуляем градиент
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = tf(inputs)
        print(outputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

Comment: Это вторая часть.

Comment: Добавил полный текст ошибки. Для чего нужно явно обращаться к атрибуту дим ?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `x = self.fcN` должно быть `x = self.fcN(x)`. Сейчас вы внутрь softmax-а передаёте не тензор x, а кусок алгоритма.